# LoginViewController: "The configured redirect_uri of the client application is invalid"

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, soundcloud

Our company has been using SoundCloud integration in our iOS apps for a while without issue. But recently our apps are getting the following error when trying to sign in:

```
"invalid client: The configured redirect_uri of the client application is invalid"
```

The redirect URI being used for an application showing this issue is:

```
0U36S5Tnl6zy830tDlQQ://oauth
```

This is the same style of redirect URI that all of our other apps are using, which have been working fine for months.

I am at a complete loss as this URI structure is that SoundCloud recommends using in their [docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#installation) and it has worked fine in the past

Comment: Does it work with an other scheme, like 'my-app'? I remember, that there was an issue with upper/lower case schemes. NSURL/NSURLConnection does not keep the case but the api could require it.

Comment: @TobiasKräntzer Aha! Got it.

It's not uppercase characters that's causing the issue, it's numbers. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that having numbers in the redirect URI causes it to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I believe is in the SC.initialize function you must enter the redirect_uri and also in the soundcloud app dashboard where you configure your app.